# How to get package name in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I stuck with a little problem. I need to get WP8 package name on (with c++), but when I use [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.aspx) functions, I only get Not Implemented Exception.

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Package^ package = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current;
Windows::ApplicationModel::PackageId^ packageId = package->Id;
Platform::String^ output = "Name: \"" + packageId->Name + "\"\n"
```

This should work, but property *package->Id* is not available in WP8, though minimum supported phone is Windows Phone 8. For example *fullName* property has remark that this is not implemented in WP8 API.

Can you help me?
Thank you

PS this function works fine in Windows Store app Solution

Answer (score 3):

You can try to get the PackageId in **C++** using the following code

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::PackageId^ packageId = Windows::Phone::Management::Deployment::InstallationManager::FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher()->First()->Current->Id;
Platform::String^ output = "Name: \"" + packageId->Name + "\"\n"
```

**C#**

```
Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher().First().Id
```

The package returned by [FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) seems have implemented the  `Current->Id`

Comment: This is not getting the current package, it is getting the first for the package. It would be better to search by id:

            var applicationId = string.Format("{{{0}}}", Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId.ToString().ToUpper());
            var package = InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher().First(i => i.Id.ProductId == applicationId);

Answer (score 1):

Not all the properties are implemented on WP8 as the documentation says and you've already found. It's a bit confusing on MSDN as in some cases the table says the API is available but the notes above say it isn't implementated on WP8.

It looks like `FullName` isn't available, but `Name` is available. There is also a Windows Phone only property `ProductId` you can use to identify your app uniquely if you need.

Comment: Is there anyway work around... I have been stuck with this exception for a while, it always throws this exception. I never took notice until i used it inside the JSON.NET serialize object function. I cant serialize an objects inside the for loop cuz it breaks from the loop the first time it encounters this exception.. Any solutions?

Comment: @alfah sounds like that's a slightly different issue. But basically if you hit `NotImplementedException` you need to not call that thing.